# How Sum and Group By with name in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to sum the money column, but I want group name and code in status.

this is the stored procedure code [Sql Server 2008]:

```
SELECT um.upmoney as 'money'
,um.pId as 'code',um.FName as 'name',up.status as 'statusmoney'
From tb_upmoney um inner join tb_pID up on up.uId=um.pId
```

Result:

```
money | code | name | statusmoney
200.00 | 00001 | fin | 1
100.00 | 00001 | fin | 1
50.00 | 00001 | fin | 1
100.00 | 00002 | welson | 1
200.00 | 00002 | welson | 2
100.00 | 00002 | welson | 2
50.00 | 00002 | welson | 2
0.00 | 00002 | welson | 2
```

**but I want:**

```
money | code | name | statusmoney
250.00 | 00001 | fin | 1
100.00 | 00002 | welson | 1
250.00 | 00002 | welson | 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `SUM(UM.upmoney)` and group remaining field like this:

```
SELECT SUM(um.upmoney) AS 'money',
       um.pId AS 'code',
       um.FName AS 'name',
       up.status AS 'statusmoney'
FROM tb_upmoney um 
    INNER JOIN tb_pID up 
    ON up.uId=um.pId
GROUP BY um.pId, um.FName, up.status
```

See the example of [GROUP BY clause with an aggregator 'SUM()'](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Select-Query/GROUPBYclausewithanaggregatorSUM.htm)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT  SUM(um.upmoney) as 'money',
        um.pId as 'code',
        um.FName as 'name',
        up.status as 'statusmoney' 
From    tb_upmoney um inner join 
        tb_pID up   on  up.uId=um.pId 
GROUP BY    um.pId,
            um.FName,
            up.status
```

[SUM (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx)

[GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(um.upmoney) as 'money',um.pId as 'code',um.FName as 'name',up.status as 'statusmoney'
From tb_upmoney um inner join tb_pID up on    up.uId=um.pId group by um.pId, um.FName, up.status
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

SELECT Sum(um.upmoney) as 'money',um.pId as 'code',um.FName as 'name',up.status as 'statusmoney'
From tb_upmoney um inner join tb_pID up on up.uId=um.pId GROUP BY um.FName, um.pId

Comment: where is status field in your group by clause