# how to merge values in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, group-by

I have a table like this :

```
Entry ID    |     Name    |     qty
12          |  Global     |    5
12          |  In Europe  |    15
12          |  In Asia    |    21
12          |  In US      |    53
18          |  Max        |    5
18          |  In Europe  |    35
18          |  In Asia    |    63
18          |  In US      |    85
```

I would like to create a stored procedure where i put a parameter " Entry ID" and exec give number @ent = 12 gives :

```
Entry ID    |  In Europe | In Asia  |  In US | Global
12          |    15      |  21      |    53  |   5
```

Can you please help me on that ?

Comment: have you tried anything..??

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980704/how-sum-and-group-by-with-name-in-stored-procedure
it's exactly what you need.

Comment: @Maurizio -- Its totally different the link you are refering for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      EntryID INT
    , Name NVARCHAR(50)
    , Qty INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (EntryID, Name, qty)
VALUES 
    (12, 'Global'     , 5),
    (12, 'In Europe'  , 15),
    (12, 'In Asia'    , 21),
    (12, 'In US'      , 53),
    (18, 'Max'        , 5),
    (18, 'In Europe'  , 35),
    (18, 'In Asia'    , 63),
    (18, 'In US'      , 85)

SELECT 
      EntryID
    , [In Europe] = SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'In Europe' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
    , [In Asia] =   SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'In Asia' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
    , [In US] =     SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'In US' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
    , [Global] =    SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Global' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
FROM @temp
GROUP BY EntryID
```

**Output:**

```
EntryID     In Europe   In Asia     In US       Global
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
12          15          21          53          5
18          35          63          85          0
```

**SP:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetEntryID

    @EntryID INT

AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
          EntryID
        , [In Europe] = SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'In Europe' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
        , [In Asia] =   SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'In Asia' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
        , [In US] =     SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'In US' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
        , [Global] =    SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Global' THEN Qty ELSE 0 END)
    FROM dbo.table1 --<-- your table
    WHERE EntryID = @EntryID
    GROUP BY EntryID

    RETURN 0

END
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:
This is dynamic query and no need to mention the column names anywhere.

```
CREATE PROC sp_Sample
@EntryID int
As
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @cols varchar(100)
DECLARE @Query varchar(1000)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from sample where [Entry Id]=@EntryID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query 
      = 'SELECT [Entry ID],' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            SELECT [Entry ID],[Name],[Qty]
            FROM sample WHERE [Entry Id]='+cast(@EntryID as varchar(5))+'
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            min(qty)
            for name in (' + @cols + ')
         ) p '

EXECUTE(@query)

END


exec sp_Sample 18
```